# mechanize create google alert in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mechanize, google-alerts

I am trying to create google alerts in ruby.  I am using mechanize.

```
@web_agent = Mechanize.new
page = @web_agent.get 'https://www.google.com/alerts'
form = page.form_with :name => 'f1'

form.q = "search keyword"
```

I am getting `nil` form value.

I am getting error:

```
undefined method `q= for nil:NilClass`
```

Google has changed html, so I need some hack.

Comment: What is the expected result because when I `get` the link, the page has no forms.

Comment: I need to create google alert. so form.q should work.

Comment: It will be ok, if there is any api for it.